# Multiple different submit buttons in one form

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've tried implementing the option explained in [this article.](http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/)

```
    public class HttpParamActionAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (actionName.Equals(methodInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        if (!actionName.Equals("Action", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return false;

        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        return request[methodInfo.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

My controller actions:

```
[HttpParamAction]
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult EditAccouncement(_AccouncementPostViewModel m)

[HttpParamAction]
[HttpPost]
public virtual PartialViewResult DeleteAnnouncement(int id)
```

My form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "announcement" + @Model.id
    }))
{
            //form values omitted
            <button type="submit" class="submitbutton" name="edit">Change details</button>
            <button type="submit" class="submitbutton" name="delete">Delete</button>
}
```

However the controller action being called is still just the Action method (which doesn't exist). Am I missing something?

Comment: Should your buttons have a 'value="<button text>"', like the article? Then your logic could reference the button name and check for the value to see if it was clicked.

Comment: Based on the example, the action methods should be renamed to Edit and Delete to match the name on the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by mismatch between your action names and the button name attributes.

The value of the name attribute on your buttons needs to match the action names, like so:

```
 <button type="submit" name="EditAccouncement">Change details</button>
 <button type="submit" name="DeleteAnnouncement">Delete</button>
```

Update: I would suggest a different approach all together. This solution seems counter-intuitive to me, and not particularly easy to follow.

You could just as easily use JavaScript (e.g. jquery) to handle the form submits 'manually', by hooking up two different event handlers to your buttons. One event would make a POST to the EditAccouncement (typo!) action and one would make a POST to the DeleteAnnouncement action.

I made a mockup on jsfiddle which demonstrates the code: http://jsfiddle.net/wmWNj/3/

Update 2: fixed typos in jsfiddle